# How to update GUI from itself which is also main class?

Tags: java, swing, oop, compiler-errors

I am kinda new to making desktop applications in java, I created a project in netbeans and created `JFrame` as main class.

Here is code:

```
public class qGenGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static funcs fcs;
static String workingDir;

public qGenGUI() {
    initComponents();
    fcs = new funcs();
    workingDir = fcs.getSetting("workingDir", "none");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
   //Removed part as I assume it's irrelevant.

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new qGenGUI().setVisible(true);
            workingDirLabel.setText(workingDir);
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to update GUI but it says:

```
non-static variable workingDirLabel cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Can someone explain to me what's happening?

Comment: Write a method for setting the text of the label.  Use the object that is an instance of the method to call it.  As an aside, this is OOP 101 and should be sorted long before attempting to create a GUI, which is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

`workingDirLabel` should be accessed from *within* the context of the qGenGUI class. The easiest way to do this is to start all work *inside* the qGenGUI constructor or a 'start' method. The `run` method runs on the EDT but is *not within* the context of a qGenGUI class instance.

The simplest change would be:

```
public qGenGUI() {
    initComponents();
    fcs = new funcs();
    workingDir = fcs.getSetting("workingDir", "none");

    // in a qGenGUI instance
    setVisible(true);
    workingDirLabel.setText(workingDir);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // not in any instance
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {
            // in a Runnable instance, but NOT within qGenGUI
            new qGenGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

Now remove the `static` modifier from the func and workingDir variables.

I recommend reading through [Lesson: Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) to understand the basics of classes/instances, what 'static' means (and how non static members work), and what it is to be "within" a context/instance.